# suspend then wake: cron of rtcwake, Beaglebone Black

Tags: configuration, beagleboneblack, suspend, wakeup

I'm trying to configure the beaglebone black [wireless version - 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT] -- running debian 9.3 stretch.

This command works fine in a bash terminal:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d "+2 minutes")
```

I've setup a cron job via

```
sudo crontab -e
```

In it, I have the following line:

```
10,40 * * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d "20 minutes")
```

However, the device is not suspending.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I debug this?

Thanks for your help

M

Answer (score 1):

The `%` char is the problem in the crontab approach. That char has a special meaning  in crontab (newline...start of stdin, see manual).

Instead of `-t $(date +%s -d "1 minutes")` you can simply use `-s 60` for sleeping 60 seconds and not having to use `%` at all. Or you might escape it with `\%` or use `'+%s'` or `"+%s"`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, however,  I used a simple example here -- I actually need to sleep based on more complex criteria.  But still, I now understand why there was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
In case there is *anyone* else trying to solve this. I don't know why this works, however it does...
1. make a script with the rtcwake comand in it....:

```
#!/bin/bash
# suspend then wake from a bash script
echo attempting to suspend!
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d "1 minutes")
```

I called this wakesleep, and placed it in /usr/local/bin (on the PATH), make it executable...

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sleepwake
```

Then added a line in  crontab, the su version:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The added line in the root crontab is of this sort of format:

```
10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/sleepwake
```

... and it works. This is a mystery to me, why the previous approach did not work, but it works.  Very keen to hear from someone what the difference between the two approaches is.